# Django- aggregating conditional child fields

Tags: django, group-by, aggregate

Let say I have the following models.  A given `Job` can run for multiple days, has multiple users on it, and those users can have various flags set (the booleans in the model):

```
class Job(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class JobEmployee(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_sup = models.BooleanField()
    is_mgr = models.BooleanField()
    timecard_complete = models.BooelanField()
```

What I would like to do is pull a list of Job IDs, Names, dates, and the count of all children, children with `is_mgr==True`, `is_sup==True`, and `timecard_complete==False` on each job's date.  So the result would look something like:

```
        Job ID                       | Job Name |    Date    | all_users | mgr | sup | missing_tc
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
978294d8-3ae8-11ea-b77f-2e728ce88125 |    Job 1 | 2020-01-05 |         8 |   2 |   0 |          4
978294d8-3ae8-11ea-b77f-2e728ce88125 |    Job 1 | 2020-01-06 |         6 |   0 |   1 |          3
f5e87902-3ae8-11ea-b77f-2e728ce88125 |    Job 2 | 2020-01-05 |        10 |   1 |   3 |          7
f5e87902-3ae8-11ea-b77f-2e728ce88125 |    Job 2 | 2020-01-06 |         5 |   0 |   1 |          0
```

How can this be done with a django query?

EDIT: Edited to bring in Job Name, as I realize I could do a normal aggregate query just on the JobEmployee table, but I need data from the job object as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

(Job.objects.values('id', 'name', 'jobemployee__date')
.annotate(all_users=Count('jobemployee'))
.annotate(mgr=Count('jobemployee__is_mgr', filter=Q(jobemployee__is_mgr=True)))
.annotate(sup=Count('jobemployee__is_sup', filter=Q(jobemployee__is_sup=True)))
.annotate(missing_tc=Count('jobemployee__timecard_complete', filter=Q(jobemployee__timecard_complete=False))))
```

Can't test it without your structure, tell me if i misprint with `)` or something like that.

Comment: The `filter=Q()` was the missing piece for me.  I missed that parameter in the docs.  Thanks!